# Multiple persistent stores

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I need to keep my data separately in different stores(user profiles). What is the best way to achieve this? I'm going to play with Persistent Object Stores in runtime. Should I simply [remove](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nspersistentstorecoordinator/1468907-remove)() the current one and [addPersistentStore](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nspersistentstorecoordinator/1468860-addpersistentstore)() to make a new or to use the early created instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have one core data stack (using `NSPersistentContainer`) for user management.  This stack would have the basic account details and the name of the sql file. (Store just the sql filename NOT the full url path, as the path can change in rare circumstance such as an iTunes restore). This would be used for the login, or select account page.

Then I would setup a second core data stack using the sql file name that was stored in the user account object. This would be the main stack used by the application.  If you need to logout, then tear down the second stack and start over.  Removing and adding store is a bad idea, as it won't deal with the row cache or other managedObjects that are floating around.

Or you could simply have one core data stack and manage the relationship so that every object belongs to a user object.  Then you would manage your fetches to only look at objects belonging to the correct user.