# Change loaded NSPersistentContainer

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have created a singleton class to manage my Core Data:

```
class CoreDataManager {
static let sharedManager = CoreDataManager()

private init() {}

lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyContainer")
    if Globals.profileNumber != 0 {
        let alternateURL = NSPersistentContainer.defaultDirectoryURL()
        let storeURL = alternateURL.appendingPathComponent("\(Globals.profileNumber)MyContainer.sqlite")
        let storeDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: storeURL)
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [storeDescription]
    }
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
}
```

But how would I change which store the `persistentContainer` is pointing to, later on in the app?

For example, the user loads the application, logs in and it loads the default sqlite file. The user then switches to another user account which should then 'close' the current database and the `persistentContainer` then needs to load a different store?

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186870/multiple-persistent-stores

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the link provided by klaudas, having one stack where entities have relationships to users is a good alternative.

If you wish to have separate stores you can try something like this:

```
class CoreDataManager {
    // The rest of your class...

    private(set) var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer?

    func setupNewPersistentContainer(completionHandler: @escaping (_ success: Bool) -> Void) {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyContainer")
        // You should also handle the case where profileNumber == 0 and your store URL can't be constructed.
        if Globals.profileNumber != 0 {
            let alternateURL = NSPersistentContainer.defaultDirectoryURL()
            let storeURL = alternateURL.appendingPathComponent("\(Globals.profileNumber)MyContainer.sqlite")
            let storeDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: storeURL)
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [storeDescription]
        }

        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // Handle the error.
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }

            let success: Bool = error == nil
            completionHandler(success)
        })

        persistentContainer = container
    }

    // The rest of your class...
}
```

Basically you put your container setup logic in a function which you call when you first initialize your stack and later when you switch accounts. You can tweak the class to make persistentContainer non-optional, or to add a flag which tracks if the store was successfully loaded.

There are a few things to note though:

1. With this approach you need to also refresh all your fetched results controllers and managed objects you keep in memory (since their persistent store is no longer reachable). The easiest way would be to reset your entire UI when switching.
2. When you setup a new container, wait for the completion handler before continuing with the account switch flow.
3. If you have any references to managed objects you can see if they are valid in a context by checking `object.managedObjectContext?.persistentStoreCoordinator == context.persistentStoreCoordinator`.